# SML - Concatenating strings in a list within a list

Tags: sml, string-concatenation, nested-lists

So I've got this list of lists of strings:

```
[["#@","**","#@"],["##","*%","##"]]
```

What I want to do is transform each inner list into a single string like this:

```
["#@**#@","##*%##"]
```

Resulting in a list of strings.

I've tried various combinations of map, foldr, and anonymous functions, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to achieve my desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function `concat : string list -> string` in the `String` structure in the Basis Library, which happens to be at the top level. Therefore, you can define your function:

```
val concatEach = map concat
```

It is going to have type `string list list -> string list`, which I guess is what you are looking for.

If you want to define your own `concat` function, you can do it this way:

```
val myConcat = foldr (op ^) ""
```

Or, without using the `op` keyword:

```
val myConcat' = foldr (fn (x, y) => x ^ y) ""
```

Comment: @ joom Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that's something I already tried and it doesn't work. Here is the result off attempting the first myConcat:


`- val myConcat = foldr (op ^) "";
val myConcat = fn : string list -> string
-
- myConcat([["#@","**","#@"],["##","*%","##"]]);
stdIn:1816.1-1816.46 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: string list
  operand:         string list list
  in expression:
    myConcat
      (("#@" :: "**" :: <exp> :: <exp>) :: ("##" :: <exp> :: <exp>) :: nil)`

Comment: Yes. `myConcat` was just a replacement for the `concat` function in the library. Have you tried the `concatEach` function I defined in my answer?

Comment: @ joom Actually, I just tried `concatEach` and it did work (I was under the impression that they worked the same way. My mistake. Thank you for your help!